# Visualize all Maven phases, goals, profiles, and plugins

Tags: maven

Is there a way print a graph or simple chart of all the phases, goals, profiles, and plugins running during a given run of Maven? It seems like this would be useful to see a big picture of what is going on. I know you can turn on debug mode via `-X`, but I'm looking for something more concise. Specifically to show which plugins are running in which phases, but showing all goals, phases, and profiles would be useful as well.

Comment: Like this: `mvn fr.jcgay.maven.plugins:buildplan-maven-plugin:list-phase`?

Comment: Yes!! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [buildplan-maven-plugin](http://buildplan.jcgay.fr/), which has the goal [`list-phase`](http://buildplan.jcgay.fr/list-phase-mojo.html) for displaying plugin executions within lifecycle phases.

```
mvn fr.jcgay.maven.plugins:buildplan-maven-plugin:list-phase
```

You can run this for a specific profile: just [tack on `-P profile-name`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Example output on an empty Maven project:

```
process-resources ---------------------------------------------------
    + maven-resources-plugin | default-resources     | resources
compile -------------------------------------------------------------
    + maven-compiler-plugin  | default-compile       | compile
process-test-resources ----------------------------------------------
    + maven-resources-plugin | default-testResources | testResources
test-compile --------------------------------------------------------
    + maven-compiler-plugin  | default-testCompile   | testCompile
test ----------------------------------------------------------------
    + maven-surefire-plugin  | default-test          | test
package -------------------------------------------------------------
    + maven-jar-plugin       | default-jar           | jar
install -------------------------------------------------------------
    + maven-install-plugin   | default-install       | install
deploy --------------------------------------------------------------
    + maven-deploy-plugin    | default-deploy        | deploy
```

Comment: Some info can be retrieved also using basic maven command. For example `mvn help:describe -Dcmd=package` will describe package phase and bounded goals to it.